# is there a way to set an interval while a `loop` is being processed

Tags: javascript, html

I just wonder is there a way to set a `interval` or run another function while a `loop` is being processed.

For example:

```js
let result = document.getElementById('result')
let time = document.getElementById('time')
function start(){
  setInterval(function(){
    time.textContent = parseFloat(time.textContent)+1
  },1000)
  setTimeout(reallystart(),0)
}
function reallystart(){
for(let i =0;i<10000;i++){
  result.innerHTML +=i
}
}
```

```html
 

<button onclick='start()'>Click</button>
  <div id='result'></div>
  <div id='time'>0</div>
```

In the example, the `interval` will only be processed after the `loop` is done, but is there a way that I could make the `interval` run while the `loop` is being processed.

Comment: The code blocks the thread. If you need to use multiple threads, please consider looking into [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is single threaded, So you can only execute a single operation at a time. You can achieve concurrency in JavaScript using [Event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

You can also execute operations using [Web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) which run in parallel with main thread, but web workers can't access UI elements. it can only communicate with main thread using messages